# Azure Blob Storage file level security

Tags: azure, security, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

i have an Azure Blob Storage with blobs that are pdf that are categorized by client number.  So for each client, they have multiple pdf reports.  I only want the client to be able to access the blobs for their client number.  (There are hundreds of clients.)

I've researched, but only see shared access signatures, but this doesn't look like what i need.

Comment: Do you need to provide link directly to the blob in the storage account ([storageaccount].blob.core.windows.net), if not, you can create an application that serves as a proxy to retrieve the pdfs from the blob and each client can get their own unique link. You would be able to implement any authentication you'd like.

Comment: Yes, should have mentioned, the client goes to a web page with a list of links to their reports.  So they need to be only able to click and view their own reports.  The issue is i don't want them to be able to guess and change the url to view another client's blob pdfs.

Answer (score 2):

There is no user-level blob permissions, other than Shared Access Signatures (and Policies).

It's going to be up to you to manage access to specific user content (and how you manage that is really up to you and your app, and how you manage a user's content metadata).

When providing a link to a user's content: if you assume all content is always private, then simply create an on-demand SAS link when requested. There's no way for the user to modify a SAS link to guess sequential numbers or *neighboring* blobs, since the SAS is for a specific URL.

As Andrés suggested, you could also use your app to stream blob content, and never worry about SAS. However, you will now be consuming resources of your web app (network, CPU, memory), and this will have an impact on your app's scale requirements. You will no longer be able to offload this to the storage service.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you already have the users authenticate, and you know which pdfs belong to them. My suggestion is to add to your current application a simple proxy (for instance if you have an MVC application, you could add a new controller and action method that will retrieve the pdfs on behalf of the user).

This way you don't need to use shared access signature and can keep the blob container private. Your controller/action method would simply use the storage SDK to retrieve the blob. An added bonus is that you could check to make sure that they are requesting their own PDF file and reject the request if they guess the ID of someone else's file.

Comment: By streaming from the app, you will consume CPU and network resources from whatever app is acting as this proxy.